# Return value to outputFields in GraphQL Mutation using a Function Generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, graphql, relayjs

I am having problems using a **function generator** inside a **GraphQL mutation**.

The function generator is being used to clean up the promise chain inside the mutation. Before refactoring the code was working fine, and at present the `console.logs` are showing the newly created writes to the database so as far as I can tell the issue is getting the final return value out of the function generator and setting it as the return value of the `mutateAndGetPayload` function.

**Error**

> Cannot set property 'clientMutationId' of undefined

I have been at this for a while now and would appreciate any advice or help.

*How do I get the return value of the function generator into the scope of the enclosing function so I can return it from that function?*

---

Below is the mutation. The database writes work fine, and the output works when it gets the right payload (it is not working, which is my main issue). The only issue is getting the `newUser` to the resolve function in the output field. I have omitted some of the code to simplify the issue.

```
const addEmployeeMutation = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'AddEmployee',
  inputFields: {
    /** this section works fine **/
  },
  outputFields: {
    attendee: {
      type: AttendeeType,
      resolve: r.compose(
          /** this section works fine **/
          r.prop('id')
        )
    }
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: (payload, {userId}) => {
    const getUser = (userId) => {
      return authorize(userId)
        .then(can => /** works fine **/ )
        .then(user => gen.next(user))
    }    
    const createHash = (plainPassword) => {
      return genSalt(10)
        .then((salt, err) => { /** works fine **/ })
        .then((hashed_password, err) => gen.next(hashed_password))
    }   
    const createUser = (payload, hashed_password, user) => {
      return new UserModel( /** works fine **/ ).save()
        .then(newUser => gen.next(newUser))
    }    
    const createProfile = (payload, newUserId) => {
      return new ProfileModel({ /** works fine **/ })
        .then(profile => gen.next(profile))
        .catch(err => {throw new GraphQLError(`Error: ${err}`)})
    }  
    let gen = generator()
    gen.next()    
    function* generator() {   
      const user = yield getUser(userId)
      console.log('USER >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', user)
      const hash = yield createHash(payload.password)
      console.log('HASH >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>', hash)   
      const newUser = yield createUser(payload, hash, user)
      console.log('NEW USER >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', newUser)    
      const newProfile = yield createProfile(payload, newUser.id)
      console.log('NEW PROFILE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', newProfile)    
      return newUser
    }
    return newUser // <- How do I get a value to here?
}
```

Comment: You don't get a value there. Generators don't make asynchronous code execute synchronously, and nothing else will. Btw, you should use `async`/`await` which is much easier to work with than a hand-written coroutine runner.

Comment: It looks like mutateAndGetPayload is returning undefined before the generator has finished its yields? I though it would hold up the containing function. I am guessing here, but if it was possible to run the generator inside the resolve function it might work but in this case it is probably not the way to go. Thanks @Bergi I will try with `async`/`await` and might post the result here if it is interesting.

Comment: Yes, since you are running the generator asynchronously the function will return before it finishes. All you can do is to return a promise for the final result (and that's what an `async function` will do as well).

Comment: Just rewrote it using `async`/`await` and it works perfectly. Thank you very much @Bergi!

Answer (score 1):

## Async Await

Thanks to some help from @Bergi I changed to using `async`/`await`.

I am posting my answer here in case someone else goes down this road and needs a hand.

The answer turns out to be a quick fix.

Change the `.then()` in each of the promises that are doing the database writes to return the needed object. And then moved them into a separate utility module.

In the mutation itself I use the following code to run through the async writes and return the required payload to the output field:

```
mutateAndGetPayload: (payload, {userId}) => {
  async function generateUser() {
    const user = await getUser(userId)
    const hash = await createHash(payload.password)
    const newUser = await createUser(payload, hash, user)
    await createProfile(payload, newUser.id)
    return newUser
  }
  return generateUser()
}
```

---

**edit**

An even neater solution, thanks again to @Bergi. I am leaving the original solution as it provides some clarity as to how `async`/`await` is being used, and demonstrates how it is possible to refactor code to improve terseness. Again, someone may find this useful.

```
mutateAndGetPayload: async function(payload, {userId}) {
  const user = await getUser(userId)
  const hash = await createHash(payload.password)
  const newUser = await createUser(payload, hash, user)
  await createProfile(payload, newUser.id)
  return newUser
}
```

---

**Explanation**

As the use of a **function generator** in the OP was asynchronous and hence non-blocking, the `mutateAndGetPayload` function was returning `undefined` before the generator had time to complete. By using `async`/`await` (in both versions) the `mutateAndGetPayload` function was blocked from completing until add the `await` values had resolved in the order in which they were specified.

Comment: Actually you should drop the `generateUser` inner function and just make `mutateAndGetPayload` `async` itself.

Comment: Thanks again @Bergi. I have left the original version to show the process, and it will help anyone coming to this pattern for the first time inside a `RelayJS` `GraphQL` mutation.

Answer (score 0):

## Ramda JS

Another approach that makes use of the `ramda` functional programming library. With some help from `q` to manage the promises.

Using ramda.js involves currying the utility functions so that they are waiting for the data to come in the right order.

```
mutateAndGetPayload: (payload, {userId}) =>
  r.compose(
    then(
      r.compose(
        then(r.last),
        r.converge(
          r.unapply(q.all),
          [
            createProfile(payload),
            createUserRole(payload),
            r.identity
          ]
        )
      )
    ),
    r.converge(
      r.compose(
        then(createUser(payload)),
        r.unapply(q.all)
      ),
      [
        r.identity,
        then(_ => createHash(payload))
      ]
    ),
    getUser
  )(userId)
```